# is there any alternative to overcome unhashable type error?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd
ci=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\welcome\Downloads\coal_india.csv')
ci
x=ci[["Deliverable_Qty","Noof_trades"]]
x.set_index("Noof_trades",inplace=True)

print(x)
import numpy as np2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.plot(x)
plt.show()
```

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

this is the error which is shown when i plot a graph for an xy stock taking its deliverable quantity and no of trades happend in a day.ro-0

Comment: Needs debugging details, like traceback, and some info on the `x` dataframe.

Comment: Maybe you want to call `x.plot()`?  Or `plt.plot(x.index, x.values)`? Maybe you want to upgrade to the latest matplotlib / numpy / pandas versions?